# VSTO Worksheet change event always return numeric values in Double?

Tags: .net, excel, vsto, vba

In VSTO Worksheet change event/Range change events contains a parameter "Target" of type Range, the Target.Value is always of type double and has value with decimal. Whereas the same in VBA has type double but can also be without decimal.

E.g If i change the value of a cell to **40**. The Target.Value in VSTO change event is **40.0** whereas in VBA its **40**. And the type for both is double.

Why there is difference in both the values?

To clarify the usecase i have attached a sample project. Please find the below link for sample project.

http://1drv.ms/1nCrhT0

In this project i have registered two events workbook open and worksheet change. In workbook open event I write some values on the range, these values are received from some external system. In worksheet change event i compare the changed value with the value already on sheet. If same then show a message box that value is same.

To execute the usecase just open the attached TestBook.xlsx. This is just a plain blank book. Two value 40 and 40.42 will be written on cells A1 and A2 respectively.
Now just double click on cell A1 and click somewhere else, the change even is fired. In the change event if its value is checked i.e Target.Value then it will be 40.0 and its type is double. Since i have not changed the values i should receive message as "Values are same" but that doesnt happen.

Can someone help me achieve the mentioned usecase.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 40 = 40.0 doesn't it? Its just that VBA does not display the decimal part if it's 0 and .Net does.

Comment: @me how - If its just about the display formats then equating the value in .Net should result in same values but it doesnt.

I have attached a sample project to clear the usecase.

Comment: @reme - The question is not w.r.t number display format. Its about its actual value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in your code;

```
if (Object.Equals(Target.Value2, value1) || Object.Equals(Target.Value2, value2))
```

**Don't use** [***`Object.Equals`***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to compare 2 values types!

Use the [***`==`***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/53k8ybth.aspx) equality operator to compare two value types / values.

```
if (ws.get_Range("A1").Value == value1)
```

Comment: Thanks @me how your solution helped me catch the root cause. The root cause was the values which i was comparing were stored in object type. i.e the value1 and Target.Value which i was comparing were first stored in an object variable and then compared. Sorry since i wasnt able to mimic the usecase but your answer helped me find the root cause. Thanks much :) :) :)